# Pin bar alerts from 28 forex pairs and 1H, 4H, D timeframes. Screener?

Tags: pine-script

It's possible to create a script checking pinbars on 28 currencies and for 3 timeframes?
I'd like to create indicator to report to my cellphone about every pinbar appear on 1H, 4H and daily charts.
It is possible to create program and it will works on TV free account?

I have already a strategy which finds pinbars way I like. But it is only for one currency of course.
I'd like to do something to check all pairs in the same time.

I read about screeners, but for now they look's hard to understand for me and to program it.